# Which container to represent dual-row list of objects?

Tags: python, qt

I have an array of objects which will be represented in the UI by two rows of UI elements. The first row will consist of a `QLabel`, a few `QPushButtons`, and a `QComboBox`. The second row will be one long `QLineEdit`. The container should be able to be updated when objects are added to or removed from the underlying array, or when those objects' properties change. Which Qt widget would be the preferred container to provide a scrollable list of these objects?

The two obvious containers would be `QListView` or `QTableView`. However, neither of these seem to handle the two-row concept clearly, specifically the long `QLineEdit` that compromises the entire second row.

Comment: Sounds like a job for a custom paint.

Comment: Why would you want to use a ListView or a TableView instead of a layout?

Comment: @Chris: I was hoping that the columns on the top row of each pair could be resized by dragging the splitters, like in a filemanager.